# Error accessing PostgreSQL using Eclipse Windows 10

Tags: java, windows, eclipse, postgresql, jdbc

I am in the process of learning Java and PostgreSQL. I am running Windows 10 with JRE 10, my IDE being Eclipse Oxygen 3a. I had written the following code:

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;

public class PostgreSQLJDBC {
   public static void main(String args[]) {
      Connection c = null;
      try {
         Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
         c = DriverManager
            .getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/testdb",
            "postgres", "123");
      } catch (Exception e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
         System.err.println(e.getClass().getName()+": "+e.getMessage());
         System.exit(0);
      }
      System.out.println("Opened database successfully");
   }
}
```

It successfully compiles. However, it gives me the following error

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.postgresql.Driver

In following the advice given in Stack Overflow, I have downloaded `postgresql-42.2.2.jar` and placed within `C:\Program Files\Java\jre-10.0.1`

I then edited my system variables and added `"C:\Program Files\Java\jre-10.0.1"` into it. However I still get the same error. Please help

Comment: Are you using any IDE(Netbeans or eclipse) ? , If yes , add that pg.jar to libraries and it should work.

Comment: Update: I imported the postgresql-42.2.2.jar file into the src folder but I noticed that among all the classes present, org.postgresql.Driver was not present. This is very strange.

Comment: The driver doesn't belong in `C:\Program Files\Java\jre-10.0.1`, it also doesn't belong in the `src` folder, don't put it there.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a .jar to your JRE is like forcing a DLL to load into every Windows application you run. There's almost never a good reason to do so.

Add the Postgres driver jar to the project's **Java Build Path**.

http://help.eclipse.org/oxygen/topic/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/reference/ref-properties-build-path.htm?cp=1_4_3_1

Maybe go through the tutorial and learn to use your tools. http://help.eclipse.org/oxygen/topic/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/gettingStarted/intro/overview.htm?cp=1_0

Comment: Thank you nitind. It worked.